# Download Attribute and Firefox for Subdomains

Tags: html, firefox, download

I'm using the download attribute for an anchor tag to download a binary file from a subdomain.

```
<!-- The hosting page is at http://foo.example.com/my-page.html -->
<div>
    <a href="http://bar.example.com/files/a/file.bin" download="1234.bin">Download</a>
</div>
```

This works fine in Chrome 30. However, in Firefox 24, I'm prompted to save with the **file.bin** filename instead of the **1234.bin** specified in the download attribute. I've read in [MDN documentation that the links must be same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download). Is this not possible with subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need, as said, to specify the origin. You can do this in bar.example.com's header by adding:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example.com
```

optionally you can add

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

for all. But be aware of the security.

This says the browser that foo.example.com is allowed to process ajax requests

Comment: Could "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com" be used in a way similar to "document.domain = 'example.com';"?

Comment: For more information read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Where to add this header